# NSDate initializer problem on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to do some basic operations with Dates on the iPhone.  I want to take a string like "2010-02-19" and turn it into a string like "Friday, Feb 19."  The strings I will be receiving will always be in 2010-02-19.  Right now, I am running the following code that works, but it produces a warning that says "NSDate may not respond to +dateWithNaturalLanguageString:"

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:scheduled];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMM dd"];

return [df stringFromDate:date];
```

The code works, but it produces that warning.  Should I worry about it, or is this OK on the iPhone.  Is there another NSDate initializer that I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+dateWithNaturalLanguageString` seems to be only available on the Mac : [NSDate Class Reference in **Mac** Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) vs. [NSDate Class Reference in **iPhone** Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also, the documentation says that:

> It may give unexpected results, and
>   its use is strongly discouraged

In the overview section of the class reference you can find the following information:

> NSDate provides several methods to
>   interpret and to create string
>   representations of dates (for example,
>   dateWithNaturalLanguageString:locale:
>   and descriptionWithLocale:). In
>   general, on Mac OS X v10.4 and later
>   you should use an instance of
>   NSDateFormatter to parse and generate
>   strings using the methods
>   dateFromString: and
>   stringFromDate:—see NSDateFormatter on
>   Mac OS X 10.4 for more details.

Given that this is only officially available on the Mac, but not on the iPhone, I wouldn't use it in an iPhone project. Even on the Mac it seems that Apple recommends using an `NSDateFormatter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSDateFormatter:dateFromString .  There's an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402367/nsdate-datefromstring-deprecated/3402389#3402389).