# NSDate dateFromString deprecated?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, xcode3.2

I'm trying to use the NSDate dateFromString method but I'm getting an warning and it's crashing the app. The code looks like:

```
NSString *pickerDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", timeSelector.date];
NSDate *defaultDate = [NSDate dateFromString:pickerDate];
```

The warning is:

```
'NSDate' may not respond to '+dateFromString'.
```

It appears that method is deprecated (in the midst of an upgrade from XCode 2 to 3.

What alternate method can I use to create a date from a string?

Comment: I assume `timeSelector` is a `UIDatePicker`, is there a reason you're converting the `date` property to a string and back to a date again?

Comment: That might be more efficient, just don't know what the code would be :/ Would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: What I mean is, are you able to do just `NSDate *defaultDate = timeSelector.date;`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` is the intended way for you to get an `NSDate` from an `NSString`.

The most basic usage is something like this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"3-Aug-10";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"d-MMM-yy";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem. 
I changed the dateFormat from @"YYYY/M/d H:m:s" to @"YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" as follows.
Then it works on my iPhone 4. (Xcode 4.5 for iOS 6.)

---

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1;
NSString *dateStr1=@"";
NSDate *gantanDate1;

dateFormatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter1 setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]; 
[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]; 
dateFormatter1.dateFormat=@"YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
dateStr1=@"2012/1/1 00:00:00"];
//  in his case,   dateStr1=pickerDate;  
gantanDate1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Silber everyone says the same thing to convert the string date to date object.Try this i think you have used two date formatters in two places where you are saving date to string and getting date from string.right try to use the same date formatters in both places. It will solve your problem.