# iOS - Converting string to non-en-GB locale NSDate returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

I have a date in format `Mon Jan 14 14:00:00 CET 2013` I try to convert it to NSDate:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y"];
NSString *dateString = @"Mon Jan 14 14:00:00 CET 2013"
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

but it doesn't work and my `date` is `nil`
Input data is in en-GB locale, my device's locale is nb-NO

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like dateFromString is depricated. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402367/nsdate-datefromstring-deprecated)

Comment: @NickThorne that's the `NSDate` class method not the `NSDateFormatter` instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing day in your format:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y"];
```

---

If it was not a typo, then next thing is to set proper locale so formatter will recognise CET timezone, for example en-GB will fix that:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// that will fix the problem with not recognized CET timezone
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-GB"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y"];
NSString *dateString = @"Mon Jan 14 14:00:00 CET 2013"
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: it was a typo :-) doesn't work with dd as well

Comment: Try setting NSTimeZone *cet = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"Europe/Paris"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:cet];

Comment: still returns nil..can it be a reason that in my current locale Mon is man and Jan is jan ?

Comment: its not case sensitive, which locale did you use?

Comment: anyway, if you'll use en-GB then CET is recognised, for en-US it won't be recognised and will return nil, I'm not sure what else you can use than en-GB

Comment: region settings on my iPhone are set to Norwegian format, data input is in En format

Comment: and if you'll try to set en-GB for that formatter (like in example above) then it doesn't work?

Comment: didn't see "locale fix", everything worked like a charm! :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think your Time Zone is wrong. Just use this code , it will work Perfectly :

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y"];
    NSString *dateString = @"Mon Jan 14 14:00:00 EDT 2013";
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"date :: %@",date);
```

It will log Output as :

```
date :: 2013-01-14 18:00:00 +0000
```

**EDIT :**

I found Something for you : [NSDateFormatter doesn't parse some timezones](http://www.openradar.me/9944011)

You can solve this by using **en_GB Locale** , as stated : "These abbreviations do still work with the en_GB locale" in [Working with Date and Time in Cocoa](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-2/) .

Comment: Except the OP wanted CET as the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this function

```
 - (NSDate*) dateFromString:(NSString*)aStr
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
    //[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSLog(@"%@", aStr);
    NSDate   *aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aStr];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return aDate;
}
```

I hope this will helps u.

Answer (score 0):

Simply "CET" is not a recognized time zone by `NSDateFormatter`.

Also the date/tine is over specified, best to not try include the day or week (Mon).

Here is an example that demonstrates working code with a recognized timezone:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = @"Mon Jan 14 14:00:00 EST 2013";
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

NSLog output

> date: 2013-01-14 19:00:00 +0000

```
NSLog(@"abbreviationDictionary: %@", [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);
```

does show

> CET = "Europe/Paris";

so this looks like an Apple bug in `NSDateFormatter`.

Report the bug at: [Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreporter.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

CET is not recognised

Try this :-

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = @"Mon Jan 14 14:00:00 2013";
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

If you still want to custom your date format try this one:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
```

Because can't invent your own formatted string syntax and expect it to work; you need to actually use a documented format as the documentation points it out : Formatters in OS X v10.8 and iOS 6.0 use version tr35-25.

-> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

If you are curious: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns